# Javascript Get Child Element by Name

Tags: javascript, dom, children

I'm passing a var `el` into a function. `el` contains previously grabbed element (using getElementById) and when I console.log `el` in the function I get the following:

[image]

The problem comes in when I try to grab an element inside of the `el` using:

```
el.getElementsByName('fname');
```

I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'getElementsByName'
```

Comment: I think that means `getElementsByName` is not a method of that object. Is el from a library like jQuery? I think you want `document.getElementsByName` without knowing what `el` is.

Comment: is there any reason not use jQuery?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `getElementsByName()` API is at the `document` object level. It's not an HTMLElement method.

You could use `querySelectorAll()` instead:

```
var fnames = el.querySelectorAll('[name=fname]');
```

It's not supported in older browsers however.