# storing multiple cell option values from table into array using javascript

Tags: javascript

I can't manage to read the users selection from a table with multiple rows and columns using javascript. The output does not show the user selection but instead only shows the option value as the index increments. Please can anyone help. Thanks!!

Javascript

```
function GetCellValues() {
    // Get table object
    var myTable = document.getElementById('my_table').tBodies[0];
    var sel1  = document.getElementById('session'); //drop down list in column 1 
    var sel2  = document.getElementById('event'); //drop down list in column 2
    var sel3  = document.getElementById('distance'); //drop down list in column 3
    var sel4  = document.getElementById('style'); //drop down list in column 4
    var s = new Array(); //initialize array to store all row values in column 1 
    var e = new Array(); //initialize array to store all row values in column 2
    var d = new Array(); //initialize array to store all row values in column 3
    var st = new Array(); //initialize array to store all row values in column 4
    var status = _("delstatus"); //to display message to user
         // first loop for each row 
        for (var r=0, n = myTable.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
             // this loop is getting each colomn/cells
            //for (var c = 0, m = myTable.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
                // get student marks in each text boxes
               s[r] = sel1.options[r].innerHTML; //attempt to read in cell user selection and store
               e[r] = sel2.options[r].text;
               d[r] = sel3.options[r].text;
               st[r] = sel4.options[r].text;    
               //st[r] = sel4.options[sel4.selectedIndex].text; 
            //}
            //display the user selection
            status.innerHTML = status.innerHTML+ '||'+n+'||'+s[r]+'|'+e[r]+'|'+d[r]+'|'+st[r]+'<br />';
        }
}
```

The HTML code:

Get Values

```
        <table class="table_norm bg_grey" width="80%" align="center" id="my_table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="text_10 dotted_lebo">Session:</th>
                    <th class="text_10 dotted_lebo">Event:</th>
                    <th class="text_10 dotted_lebo">Distance:</th>
                    <th class="text_10 dotted_lebo">Style:</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr align="center">
                    <td class="text_10 dotted_lebo">
                        <select name="session" id="session" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" >
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="1">Session1</option>
                            <option value="2">Session2</option>
                            <option value="3">Session3</option>
                            <option value="4">Session4</option>
                            <option value="5">Session5</option>
                            <option value="6">Session6</option>
                            <option value="7">Session7</option>
                            <option value="8">Session8</option>
                            <option value="9">Session9</option>
                            <option value="10">Session10</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>


                    <td class="text_10 dotted_lebo">
                        <select name="event" id="event" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                            <option value="8">8</option>
                            <option value="9">9</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>


                    <td class="text_10 dotted_lebo">
                        <select name="distance" id="distance" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="25m">25m</option>
                            <option value="50m">50m</option>
                            <option value="100m">100m</option>
                            <option value="200m">200m</option>
                            <option value="400m">400m</option>
                            <option value="800m">800m</option>
                            <option value="1500m">1500m</option>
                            <option value="1km">1km</option>
                            <option value="3km">3km</option>
                            <option value="5km">5km</option>
                            <option value="10km">10km</option>
                            <option value="4x25m">4x25m</option>
                            <option value="4x50m">4x50m</option>
                            <option value="4x100m">4x100m</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>

                    <td class="text_10 dotted_lebo">
                        <select name="style" id="style" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="Freestyle">Freestyle</option>
                            <option value="Backstroke">Backstroke</option>
                            <option value="Breastroke">Breastroke</option>
                            <option value="Butterfly">Butterfly</option>
                            <option value="IM">IM</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>   
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWDs5.png

Comment: Why are you storing option value rather than selected one?

Comment: I want to store user selection but only seem to get the option value.

Comment: Can you explain what is exactly user selection? the code i've provided will surely store the value which use have selected. It is user selection right?

Comment: Please help to visualize what exactly you need to store. and how it will look like?

Answer (score 0):

**Provided if you just want to show the values of select list which are selected by user here is the code you should write**

```
function GetCellValues() {
    // Get table object
    var myTable = document.getElementById('my_table').tBodies[0];
    var sel1  = document.getElementById('session'); //drop down list in column 1 
    var sel2  = document.getElementById('event'); //drop down list in column 2
    var sel3  = document.getElementById('distance'); //drop down list in column 3
    var sel4  = document.getElementById('style'); //drop down list in column 4
    var status = _("delstatus");
    status.innerHTML = status.innerHTML+ '||'+sel1.selectedValue +'||'+sel2.selectedValue +'|'+sel3.selectedValue +'|'+sel4.selectedValue +'<br />';

}
```

There is no need to iterate through table rows if you have element ids with you.
If you want to store also the option text of the selected element then you can do that like following.

```
sel1.options[sel1.selectedIndex].text
```

In case you have multiple rows which will have same select lists on each then better not to assign ids to each of them and provide name instead. Ids should be unique for each html element and you can have similar name though. Hence give them proper names and then iterate through each row as you are doing. Now as you need pure javascript refer following post and have a look how to find child elements by their respective name in javascript.

**[Javascript Get Child Element by Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842951/javascript-get-child-element-by-name)**

Comment: Hi KD, I tried uploading an image but need 10 reputations to do that...not sure what that means!!

Comment: Will sel.selectedValue provide the cell data the user selected for lots of rows at the same time?

Comment: Currently sel1.selectedValue gives an undefined error response.

Comment: Also sel1.selectedIndex gives the problem of the predefined option value, i.e.session or session2, etc depending on the selectedIndex value, which is 0 or 1.

Comment: Do you have multiple table rows with the same select list? If it is like that then you can't assign them similar ids. The id of each html element should be different. Try to provide unique ids and then try to access them with the help of your **for loop counter**. That will surely help

Comment: managed to load a URL link to image the user needs to fill in. See above below the code I inserted.

Comment: Thats a pity that each html element in this instance needs its own unique ID as I don't know how many times a row will be added and then filled in. Surely the data can be read in one row at a time?

Comment: Yeah rather do one thing. dont assign them ids at all. and try to find elements by their name. Remember the names of the elements can be same but ids should be different. Either iterate through each row and find there child select tags with respective names using javascript or simply switch to jQuery and make it simpler for you do do so.. you have these two options :)

Comment: check my updated answer and you will find correct guideline to do so. Mark it as answer if it helps you :)