# Vanilla JS - Get element by name of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementsbyname

I need to translate this jQuery command in JavaScript:

```
$('#edit_pickup_date_modal').find('input[name=type]').val('2');
```

I tried to:

```
var element = document.getElementById('edit_pickup_date_modal');
var input = element.getElementsByName('type')[0];
input.value = '2'
```

but I got the error "element.getElementsByName is not a function"

Comment: [Javascript Get Child Element by Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842951/javascript-get-child-element-by-name)

Comment: have you tried ```var elms = document.querySelectorAll('#edit_pickup_date_modal input[name=type]'); elms.forEach(x => { x.value = 2 } )```? Maybe on the oldest browser you have to cast the **NodeList** returned from *Element.prototype.querySelectorAll* to a normal **Array** with ```Array.from(elms)```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `getElementById` to get the tag with id 'edit_pickup_date_modal'. Than search with `querySelector` for the first INPUT-field with name = 'type' and set the value.

```js
document.getElementById('edit_pickup_date_modal').querySelector('input[name=type]').value=2;
```

```html
<div id='edit_pickup_date_modal'>
  <div>
    <input name ='type'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

For more info on searching for the elements on DOM such as `getElementById`, `querySelector`, please refer [here](https://javascript.info/searching-elements-dom)

```js
const modalDiv = document.getElementById('edit_pickup_date_modal')

const inputElem = modalDiv.querySelector('input[name=type]');

inputElem.value = 2
```

```html
<div id="edit_pickup_date_modal">
  <input name="type"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also combine the whole operation into a single `querySelector`:

```js
document.querySelector('#edit_pickup_date_modal input[name=type]').value=2;
```

```html
<div id='edit_pickup_date_modal'>
  <div>
    <input name ='type'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent vanilla function for the jQuery `$('#edit_pickup_date_modal').find('input[name=type]').val('2');`

is:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#edit_pickup_date_modal input[name=type]').forEach(function(obj, index){
    obj.value=2;
});

//If you need to take the first element only.
document.querySelector('#edit_pickup_date_modal input[name=type]').value=3;
```

```html
<div id="edit_pickup_date_modal">
  <input name="type"/>
   <input name="type"/>
    <input name="type"/>
     <input name="type"/>
</div>
```

And it means:

> for each `input[name=type]` inside the element with the ID `edit_pickup_date_modal`, assign to its `value` property the constant value 2.